# Print another PDF file from Odoo POS

Tags: javascript, odoo

In Odoo v15 POS, I want to print another PDF with the POS order receipt when I click a custom button.

Each order I have has 1 or more tickets .. I've added another button called "Print Tickets" next to "Print Receipt".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
<t t-name="ReceiptScreenAddPrintTicket" t-inherit="point_of_sale.ReceiptScreen"    t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('default-view')]" position="replace">
        <div class="default-view">
                <div class="actions">
                    <h1>How would you like to receive your receipt<t t-if="currentOrder.is_to_invoice()"> &amp; invoice</t>?</h1>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <div class="button print" t-on-click="printReceipt">
                            <i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print Receipt
                        </div>
                        <div class="button print" t-on-click="printReceipt">
                            <i class="fa fa-ticket"></i> Print Tickets
                        </div>
<!-- Rest of the code -->
```

The printReceipt function is inside the file ReceiptScreen.js :

```
 async printReceipt() {
            const currentOrder = this.currentOrder;
            const isPrinted = await this._printReceipt();
            if (isPrinted) {
                currentOrder._printed = true;
            }
        }
```

The _printReceipt function is inside the file AbstractReceiptScreen.js :

```
odoo.define('point_of_sale.AbstractReceiptScreen', function (require) {
'use strict';

const { useRef } = owl.hooks;
const { nextFrame } = require('point_of_sale.utils');
const PosComponent = require('point_of_sale.PosComponent');
const Registries = require('point_of_sale.Registries');

/**
 * This relies on the assumption that there is a reference to
 * `order-receipt` so it is important to declare a `t-ref` to
 * `order-receipt` in the template of the Component that extends
 * this abstract component.
 */
class AbstractReceiptScreen extends PosComponent {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.orderReceipt = useRef('order-receipt');
    }
    async _printReceipt() {
        if (this.env.pos.proxy.printer) {
            const printResult = await this.env.pos.proxy.printer.print_receipt(this.orderReceipt.el.outerHTML);
            if (printResult.successful) {
                return true;
            } else {
                await this.showPopup('ErrorPopup', {
                    title: printResult.message.title,
                    body: printResult.message.body,
                });
                const { confirmed } = await this.showPopup('ConfirmPopup', {
                    title: printResult.message.title,
                    body: this.env._t('Do you want to print using the web printer?'),
                });
                if (confirmed) {
                    // We want to call the _printWeb when the popup is fully gone
                    // from the screen which happens after the next animation frame.
                    await nextFrame();
                    return await this._printWeb();
                }
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return await this._printWeb();
        }
    }
    async _printWeb() {
        try {
            window.print();
            return true;
        } catch (err) {
            await this.showPopup('ErrorPopup', {
                title: this.env._t('Printing is not supported on some browsers'),
                body: this.env._t(
                    'Printing is not supported on some browsers due to no default printing protocol ' +
                        'is available. It is possible to print your tickets by making use of an IoT Box.'
                ),
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
}

Registries.Component.add(AbstractReceiptScreen);

return AbstractReceiptScreen;
});
```

I was digging inside the code trying to understand the process of printing used by Odoo but I did not find the right way.
When I click "Print Receipt" this window opens so I can print the receipt, from where exactly in the Odoo source code is getting the receipt information (so I can edit what's gonna be printed ) ?

[image]

I am just asking for ideas not a ready code, I am learning and that's just a new tough challenge.

In every pos.order I have a field called "origin" (accessible by `receipt.origin`). I can use it to run an rpc query to get a list of dictionaries containing the needed information of the related tickets to be printed, I can handle that.

What I want to know, please, an idea to print another PDF file besides the order receipt.

I think about using the same XML file "OrderReceipt.xml" that contains the receipt and using t-if, can I handle what to get when I click each of the Print buttons ?

Which means when I click "Print Receipt" I get the first part of "OrderReceipt.xml" containing the order, orderlines and payment details, and when I click "Print Tickets", I get the second part of "OrderReceipt.xml" containing the tickets.

is it possible ? or I need to look for another way ? like creating another XML file ...